# How can I disable downloading javascript with Loadrunner Web (Click and Script)?

Tags: javascript, loadrunner

Is there a way to do this in recording options? I tried recording the script as Web (Click and Script)  - GUI-based script but it downloads the javascript file. Recording using the HTML-based script yields the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

OK.   I am going to ask a bizarre question.   If your clients are all going to be downloading the javascript files based upon the requests generated by the parsing of the web page then why would you want to exclude the load from those requests from your web server?

A known deviation from user behavior such as this would have to be documented and included with every result set and would (for me) send up red flags on whether the test actually generates the same load as a actual user.